# How to prevent sidebar from closing and opening when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, function, toggle

I have two functions. The first closes the sidebar onscroll and the second opens it on hover. The problem is when i click on one of the links and it takes me to a new page the sidebar quickly closes and opens. I want it to not do that when clicking on any of the links. I hope this is ok. I still battle to ask questions on here.

```
let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos ? document.getElementById("navbar").style.left = "0" : document.getElementById("navbar").style.left = "-8vw"
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}

navbar.onmouseover = function () {
if (navbar = "0px") {
document.getElementById("navbar").style.left = "0px";
}
}
```

Comment: `if (navbar = "0px") {` is probably supposed to be something like `if (navbar.style.left == "0px") {`

Comment: More importantly: where do these links lead? Somewhere down the same page, I assume?

Comment: The function is working fine as it is. It's objective is to open the navbar on hover. The problem is that it's fighting with the top function. Because the one is telling it that when you go to a new page close the navbar but because the mouse is still over it it pulls it out again. So the two functions are at war. I need a function that says if you click on the link keep the navbar open if that makes sense. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It's just a simple one page portfolio website. With Home, About, Skills and so on.

Comment: The function is "working fine" by sheer accident; if (navbar = "0px") is nonsense in more than one way. `navbar` is an HTMLElement, not a string possibly equal to "0px". If you had used the proper operator for comparisons (`==`) this test would've always failed. Since you are using the assignment operator instead, the test will never fail, because your code will a) overwrite `navbar` with `"0px"`, b) evaluate to `if (navbar)`, with `navbar` being `"0px"`, i.e. a truthy value. But it doesn't matter that the test never fails because setting `style.left` to 0 is always supposed to happen anyway.

Comment: Regarding your actual issue: use a variable like `mouseOverNav` and set it in onmouseover / onmouseleave. That way you can check inside your onscroll handler if the mouse is over the navbar.